# Using libcurl to store retured data in a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, http, shared-ptr, libcurl

I am using a `shared_ptr` to hold the data returned by a `libcurl` write function. The following code works fine.

```
std::stringstream http_data;
...
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &http_data);
...
*br->read_buffer = http_data.str();
```

`read_buffer` is a `shared_ptr` to a standard `string`.

But is there any way I can increase efficiency by passing the `shared_ptr` into the `curl_easy_setopt`. I can't find a way that works, but I am new to using `shared_ptr`.

Further edited to show my writefunction.

```
size_t bf_callback(const char* in, size_t size, size_t num, char* out) {
    std::string data(in, (size_t)size * num);
    *((std::stringstream*) out) << data;
    return size * num;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine"? `curl_easy_setopt` does not accept pointers to `std::stringstream`. It does accept any pointer you like, but you have to be careful about what you put into it. See [`curl_easy_setopt()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html). This code might compile, but it most certainly won't do what you want.

Comment: Why not just pass a `std::string`?

Comment: You can pass a pointer to it, or you could pass `br` (whatever that is). You just need to adjust your write callback accordingly.

Comment: @Galik curl is a C library, it doesn't know how to use a `std::string`. It writes to the buffer using `fwrite()`, so the parameter needs to be a `FILE*`.

Comment: @J.Schultke Given that the code above works, it's not unreasonable to assume that a `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION `, written in C++, has been provided.

Comment: @J.Schultke By works fine I mean it retunrs the (json) data I expected from the website. But I should have said there is a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.

Comment: @J.Schultke, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA takes any type of pointer. It doesn't matter what type of pointer it is passed to if CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION correctly handles it as its 4th argument. libcurl take care of WRITEDATA by means of WRITEFUNCTION.

Comment: @J.Schultke It doesn't matter what language `CURL` is written in, if you pass a `std::string*` as the `void*` parameter and cast it back to a `std::string*` in the callback function, it will work fine according to `C++` rules.

Comment: I've been trying to modify my WRITEFUNCTION but not succeeded. Could anyone provide a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION that will return the data into a std::shared_ptr<std::string> (or std::shared_ptr<std::stringstream>).

Comment: @Steve Whatever your `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is currently doing for your `std::stringstream` should work just fine for any type of object you pass it. You just have to make sure you pass in the same type you use in your `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. What is your `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` code doing?

Comment: @Galik I have added this to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the most efficient way would be to pass a `std::string` to the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback and then swap that `std::string` with the destination string only if the transfer is a success.

Something like this:

```
std::size_t bf_callback(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t num, void* userdata)
{
    if(auto s = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(userdata))
    {
        // only get here if userdata is not nullptr
        s->append(ptr, ptr + (size * num));
        return size * num;
    }

    return 0; // indicate error to framework
}

//...

std::string http_data; // working string

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &http_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &bf_callback);

CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);

if(code != CURLE_OK)
    throw std::runtime_error(curl_easy_strerror(code));

// now we are safe to use the working std::string

std::swap(*br->read_buffer, http_data); // std::swap can't throw exception
```